# problems in copying a csv file from s3 to redshift

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, utf-8, amazon-redshift

i am getting the following error if i run a copy command to copy contents of a .csv file in s3 to a table in redshift.

error:"String length exceeds DDL length".

i am using following copy command:

```
COPY enjoy from 's3://nmk-redshift-bucket/my_workbook.csv' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=”****”;aws_secret_access_key=’**** ' CSV QUOTE '"' DELIMITER ',' NULL AS '\0'
```

i figured lets open the link given by s3 for my file through was console.
link for the work book is :
[link to my s3bucket cvs file](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nmk-redshift-bucket/my_workbook.csv)

the above file is filled with many weird characters i really don't understand.
the copy command is taking these characters instead of the information i have entered in my csv file.So hence leading to string length exceeded error.

i use sql workbench to query.My 'stl_load_errors' table in redshift has raw_field_values component similar to the chars in the link i mentioned above, thats how i got to know how its taking in the input

i am new to aws and utf-8 configs. so please i appreciate help on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you provide points to a `.xlsx` file (but has a `.csv` extension instead of `.xlsx`), which is actually a zip file.

That is why you see those strange characters, the first 2 being `'PK'`, which means it is a zip file.

So you will have to export to `.csv` first, before using the file.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.